# Waffle-Ecto Changeset Field Image Resize | Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to apply ImageMagick transformations to a Waffle-Ecto image in a `@changeset` before I upload to my AWS bucket. Here is my schema

```
defmodule App.Images.Image do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  use Waffle.Ecto.Schema

  schema "images" do
    field(:image, App.ImageUploader.Type)
  end

  def changeset(listing, attrs) do
    listing
    |> cast_attachments(attrs, [:image])
  end
end
```

How do I write code to change the size of my image and then upload the
`@changeset`? I used following article to get my images on AWS, but it hasn't helped me to solve this problem. https://curiosum.com/blog/how-upload-file-elixir-waffle

Answer (score 1):

[`Ecto.Changeset.change/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#change/2) is your friend. After the `cast_attachments/3` call, you get back a changeset that might be modified directly.

It is hard to tell without further details, but it seems you’d have a `Plug.Upload` instance after casting, which one might use to retrieve the image, do whatever is needed (e. g. change the size), and then amend the changeset with the new value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been trying to figure out how to resize a photo before upload to S3 bucket using virtual fields, however I can't seem to understand when the transform/2 function is applied because according to my own diagnostics it is impossible to tell when the transformation is occurring (ei: it seems to be called when an image is uploads using Repo.insert, when it is retrieved using a Image.Uploader.url function, etc.. How can I simply adjust photos before upload and not worry about further transformations and such.